# Rails 3/Devise how to trigger the forgotten password from a model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Its pretty simple: how do I trigger rails to send the forgotten password email:

```
def send_invitation
     raise "Tell devise to send email"
end
```

Thats where I need to send the email from.  That gets triggered in few instances but I need it to work...

Something like

```
def send_invitation
   DeviseMailer.forgotten_password.deliver
end
```

Thats not the right code, I don't even know where to look

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's `send_reset_password_instructions`, you can find it by looking at the class documentation that you add when you specify `recoverable` in the model, [Recoverable documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable/ClassMethods). The same is true for the other Devise options such as `confirmable` too.

Comment: So if I am call this method in the User model, in an after_create callback would this work: send_reset_password_instructions(attributes => {:email => self.email})

Comment: You would call it in the model as `self.send_reset_password_instructions`, the attributes part is unnecessary as it's not a class method.

Comment: Thanks very much I dug a little deeper and figured it out: User(self)sent_reset_password_instructions

Comment: when I call the send_reset_password_instructions I'm getting an error returned saying:  535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted   got past a bunch of hurdles but this one is troubling.  I'm using this in an API where I hacked in token authentication...